# Responsive image slider + swipe

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design, swap

I'm looking for a responsive image slider where you can swap through the images.
This is what I want:

[image]

I've tried this tutorial: http://www.awwwards.com/demo/touchSwipe-gallery-demo.html
But when I set the variable 'maxImages' on more then 3 it doesn't show more then 3 images.

Does anyone knows a good js library that works on all devices? (iphone, ipad, ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can make some changes like this :

```
$(function() {
            var IMG_WIDTH = new Array(0,500,200,500),
            currentImg = 0,
            maxImages = 6;
            speed = 500,
            imgs = $("#imgs");
            var countIMG = 0;
            $.each(IMG_WIDTH, function(index, value) {
                countIMG += value;
            });
           $("#imgs").css('width',countIMG+50);
            //Init touch swipe
            imgs.swipe({
                triggerOnTouchEnd: true,
                swipeStatus: swipeStatus,
                allowPageScroll: "vertical"
            });

            function swipeStatus(event, phase, direction, distance, fingers)
            {
                if (phase == "move" && (direction == "left" || direction == "right"))
                {
                    var duration = 0;

                    if (direction == "left")
                        scrollImages((IMG_WIDTH[currentImg] * currentImg) + distance, duration);

                    else if (direction == "right")
                        scrollImages((IMG_WIDTH[currentImg] * currentImg) - distance, duration);
                }

                else if (phase == "cancel")
                {
                    scrollImages(IMG_WIDTH[currentImg] * currentImg, speed);
                }

                else if (phase == "end")
                {
                    if (direction == "right")
                        previousImage()
                    else if (direction == "left")
                        nextImage()
                }
            }

            function previousImage()
            {
                currentImg = Math.max(currentImg - 1, 0);
                scrollImages(IMG_WIDTH[currentImg] * currentImg, speed);
            }

            function nextImage()
            {
                currentImg = Math.min(currentImg + 1, maxImages - 1);
                scrollImages(IMG_WIDTH[currentImg] * currentImg, speed);
            }

            function scrollImages(distance, duration)
            {
                imgs.css("-webkit-transition-duration", (duration / 1000).toFixed(1) + "s");

                var value = (distance < 0 ? "" : "-") + Math.abs(distance).toString();

                imgs.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(" + value + "px,0px,0px)");
            }
        });
```

It's not tested but it must be good ..

Answer (score 1):

For more then 3 images, you have juste to add this line `$("#imgs").css('width',maxImages*IMG_WIDTH+50);` after `imgs = $("#imgs");`

[jQuery Mobile is simple to use for devices](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: That way I always get an open space at my last image. See: http://cl.ly/image/2u1n431G3j24

Comment: Juste add 30 rather then 50 in the width or less

Comment: This is what I have now: 
http://nielsvroman.be/tapcrowd/slider/index.html  Do you know why you keep scrolling right?

Comment: because some images have width 200 px not 500px , they must all have the same width .. look at this => IMG_WIDTH = 500,

Comment: And isn't this possible to do for images with a different width?

Answer (score 1):

The Best I've seen & used is [**Royal Slider**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/),

[**http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

It does cost money, but it's an reasonable price, but I do believe it's an elegant responsive slider.

[**Image Slider Demo**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/full-width/)